# Configure RRAS to send DNS search domain to Mac L2TP VPN client

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, rras, l2tp

Is there any way to make RRAS send the default search domain (ie the connection's search domain, the FQDN of the domain in question) to Mac clients who connect via L2TP? Or is this something that just has to be configured on each connecting client?

Comment: If you use DHCP to assign ip addresses to RRAS clients then the RRAS clients should be given the DNS suffix configured in your DHCP scope, which should be configured to be the DNS suffix of your internal domain.

Comment: Thanks Joe. I was assigning them using the other option.